# Run the same tests multiple times with varying parameters in the google test framework

Tags: unit-testing, googletest

I have several tests e.g. Test01, Test02, Test03. The tests need to run on multiple devices that are connected to the system. I have a class that detects the number of devices. I thought about value-parameterized tests using testing::TestWithParam option. However, as per the logic, each test will be executed on all of the devices before passing on to the next test. The challenge here is that I need to re-discover the devices connected to my system before starting each test. My question - is there a way in google test to execute all the tests on one device, then pass on to the next device and do the same?

Comment: Why do you have "multiple devices"? What are you trying to achieve? This looks more like an end-to-end or integration test, not a unit test.

Comment: It's sort of a pulse check for each device.  Hence I wouldn't call that an end-to-end test.

Comment: I still don't understand why you use multiple devices? Do you need to run the test on different configurations, such as different OS/versions, libraries/versions?

Comment: Anyways, this does not sound like something Google Test is designed to handle. I think you need some kind of test orchestration or continuous integration tool.